# how scroll custom editext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a custom EditText that in its touch event wrote the code for display keyboardview.now I can't scroll it and with click on it can't locate cursor in touched position.I find code for locate cursor in touched position that it work correct only when edittext did not scroll.

code is:

```
Layout layout = ((EditText) text).getLayout();
if (layout != null)
{
    int line = layout.getLineForVertical((int) event.getY());
    int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, event.getX());
    ((EditText)text).setSelection(offset);
}
```

please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 2 scrollView(as Royston said) inside 1 layout (the consequence is on some phone it appears to be laggy)
Here are some code snippet for that:
first on xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/myparentScrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mychildScrollView"

        <TextView
        / >


</ScrollView>
```

And add this on code behind

```
 parentScrollView= (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myparentScrollview);
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         //Log.v(TAG,"PARENT TOUCH");
         findViewById(R.id.childScrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
        }
    });
childScrollView= (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.childScrollView);
childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         //Log.v(TAG,"PARENT TOUCH");
         findViewById(R.id.mychildScrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enclose your EditText inside ScrollView to enable scrolling